# WPF Content View not displaying DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ContentControl which will not display any XAML from its DataTemplate, and I feel certain that the problem I'm facing will be obvious for those with better WPF codemancy than myself.  I have substituted "Object" for my object name where appropriate for confidentiality reasons.

In my MainWindow.xaml I have this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ObjectDetailView"
                Margin="20,20,20,20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ObjectListView}"
                Template="{DynamicResource DetailControlTemplate}" 
                ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DetailDataTemplate}"/>
```

I keep my templates in separate files to keep code readable.  The template is in a DataResources.xaml file that is being successfully used for the ListView.  The code for the content/template in question is:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DetailControlTemplate">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource ObjectDetailBorderStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type model:Object}">
  <!-- Valid XAML -->
</DataTemplate>
```

In my Designer (both in VS and Blend) The border/background gradient displays, but nothing further.  Same for the running program.

If I move the `<!-- Valid XAML -->` into the Control Template, it displays fine, but I don't believe that's kosher, and I also don't believe that the data-binding will work that way. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

ObjectListView is a ListView populated dynamically from my VM, and I'm using MVVM.  That all works just fine. I'd prefer this ContentControl only appears once there is a valid selected object in the list view, but that's UX sugar at this point, thus my only concern is to get this content control displaying my model's data.

I'm also fairly new to StackOverflow, so if I missed anything or made an error in posting this question, please let me know.  I've not had luck with searching for this issue over the last few hours, as I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: What happens if you move the DataTemplate to before the ContentTemplate in the resource dictionary?

Comment: No noticeable effect.

Comment: And SelectedItem in the ListView is definitely model:Object? And it's not null? Btw you could hide the content control with a style on it that has a trigger that sets visibility to Collapsed or Hidden if Content={x:Null} but as you say that can wait.

Comment: I believe SelectedItem is null when the program first starts.  There are things like lines and labels that are static that I would expect to be there without a model backing it.  Would it fail to display these without an object?  Once I click on one of my ListView items, I know it sets the SelectedItem from my debugging.  Thanks for the hint regarding Visibility, no idea why I never thought of that, as I was aware of it in some (undoubtably cobwebbed) corner of my mind.

Comment: Absent a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is. That said, there are at least 2 things I see worth changing to see if it fixes your problem: **1)** Use `<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>`, or **2)** Don't set `ContentTemplate` at all; instead, remove the `x:Key` from your template and let the automatic template lookup behavior in WPF find the template for you. (I also would not use `DynamicResource` unless you have a very good reason to do so...I don't see anything here that looks like one)

Comment: Adding the "Template" in ContentTemplate fixed it immediately.  Thank you.  And yes, I generally avoid DynamicResource, it was part of the things I tried to solve this issue that I forgot to rewind back when I posted the question.  My error.  In the future I'll do my best to provide your M,C,V example, thank you for that link as well.  How do I properly credit you?

Answer (score 2):

Two things. You did not set the actual `Content` of the ContentControl, but only its DataContext. You should instead write this:

```
<ContentControl ...
    Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ObjectListView}"
    Template="{DynamicResource DetailControlTemplate}" 
    ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DetailDataTemplate}"/>
```

And your ControlTemplate is missing a `TargetType`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DetailControlTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource ObjectDetailBorderStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Without the TargetType, the ContentPresenter's properties aren't set by default, and you would have to set them explicitly like

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DetailControlTemplate">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource ObjectDetailBorderStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter
            Content="{Binding Content,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            ContentTemplate="{Binding ContentTemplate,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.  While none of these tricks fixed my issue (see my comment above) Fixing the target type allows me to use the `{Template Binding ..}` instead of directly specifying the resource, which is important.  Also, using Content instead of DataContext an important improvement as well.  I'm slightly at a loss for how to credit all parties involved with assisting me.